# Paste a column into a single row with comma separation

Tags: r

I have a dataframe below,

```
  > Company
      Name
   1  ABB
   2  Siemens
   3  GE
   4  KF
   5  Woodrich
```

I need to have below out put

```
 > Company1 <- c("ABB","Siemens","GE","KF","Woodrich")
```

I tried the below code but not able to get.

```
    Company1<- paste(Company$Name,sep = "",collapse = ",")
```

Comment: Your expected output is unclear. It makes it look like you just want the vector pulled out from the `data.frame` since your expected output looks equivalent to `Company1 <- Company$Name`.

Answer (score 1):

We can do:

```
 paste(t(df),collapse = ",")
[1] "ABB,Siemens,GE,KF,Woodrich"
```

Or simply:

```
paste(t(df))
[1] "ABB"      "Siemens"  "GE"       "KF"       "Woodrich"
```

Or as suggested by @akrun :

```
toString(t(df))
```

Data:

```
df<-structure(list(Name = c("ABB", "Siemens", "GE", "KF", "Woodrich"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
))
```

Comment: Or `toString(t(df))`

Answer (score 0):

```
Company1 <- as.character(unlist(as.list(Company)))
```

Comment: Thanks, But there are no commas in between. I need the output as           
 Company1 <- "ABB","Siemens","GE","KF","Woodrich"

Answer (score 0):

To get a vector:

```r
Company <- data.frame(name = c("ABB", "Siemens", "GE", "KF", "Woodrich"))
Company1 <- as.vector(Company$name)
```

If you do `Company1 <- Company$name`, you'll get a factor.
Using `paste()` creates a string, not a vector. With the vector you'll have 5 elements, with the string just one.

```r
> Company2 <- paste(Company$Name, sep = "", collapse = ",")
> Company2
[1] "ABB,Siemens,GE,KF,Woodrich"
> Company1
[1] "ABB"      "Siemens"  "GE"       "KF"       "Woodrich"
```